# Haskell Extension for Visual Studio Code starts a new Haskell Language Server for each file

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-language-server

I recently installed the Haskell extension in Visual Studio Code which is powered by the Haskell Language Server. Each time I open a different Haskell file in the editor a new process named "haskell-language-server-1.0.0-linux-8.6.5" is created. The result of this is that each time I hover over a word in my program I see everything, like types or errors written two times. More important each of these processes consumes about 1 Gb of RAM and eventually my system crashes. Is there anything I could do to avoid all of this?

Comment: https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell/issues Discuss with the developers please.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered The same problem.

To **solve** this problem, I opened the **folder** containing all wanted files, i.e.,*File -> Open Folder*. This solution is sufficient if you have all wanted files located within a **single folder**. This folder can contain other folders that also contain haskell files (or any similiar **recursive** file structure), and still only one language server will be created

If you want to use files that are located in **different folders**, there are **two options** depending on how many language servers you are willing to tolerate:

1. **Single** Language Server: **Move** all folders containing wanted files to a **new folder**; as visual studio code views this as a single folder, only a single language server is spawned.
2. **Specific Limit** of Language Servers: Create a **workspace** and add folders containing wanted files to it. More specifically: **a)** Close any current workspace, folder, or file( these actions can be found at the bottom of the file menu), **b)** add wanted folders to workspace by *File->Add Folder to Workspace*, **c)(optional)** If you want to use such a setup in the future you can save this workspace by *File -> Save WorkSpace as*. Each added folder that is added directly through the *Add folder to Workspace* action will spawn a new language server;it is the number of folders opened **this way** that determines the amount, not the **total amount** of folders open.